# JQuery based Full Width Responsive Image Slider corrupt?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am developing my first responsive full width image slider in JQuery.
I've been working with JQuery before but never image sliders so I am not sure if its my code that is corrupt or if its the cycle2 that is playing a game with me.

So the issue I am having is that when I open my webpage to see the slider itself its not showing the pictures. I am leaning against the idea of the cycle2 file being outdated or something but I cant know for sure unless someone who uses it alot can confirm it.

To me my code looks perfect, I cant find any issues since it is such a short code.

Here is what my issue looks like https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNTjZ.jpg

And here is the source code for my file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Full Width Responsive Image Slider</title>

<script type="text/javascript src="C:\Users\user\Desktop\Development\Full Width Slider Varga\js\jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript src="C:\Users\user\Desktop\Development\Full Width Slider Varga\js\jquery.cycle2.min.js"></script>

</head>



<body>

    <div class="cycle-slideshow">
        <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\Development\Full WIdth Slider Varga\images\Untitled.png">
        <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\Development\Full WIdth Slider Varga\images\wp.png">
        <img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\Development\Full WIdth Slider Varga\images\wp2.png">
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Full Width Responsive Image Slider</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="cycle-slideshow">
    <img src="images/Untitled.png">
    <img src="images/wp.png">
    <img src="images/wp2.png">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1qjgwz31/

Comment: That made the images show up but it is not working as a slideshow it is not fading by default as it should. Could this be because of cycle2?

Comment: Still the same outcome.

Comment: Sure thing! I will try to explore what might make this issue occur meanwhile.

Comment: Try again. I had the paths  to the javascript setup to be used if you were on a server. SInce your running it locally you need the http://

Comment: Thank you it is now working like a charm. I am not 100% how this worked and what the actual fix was (If you got time to explain I would love to hear it) but hey thanks again!

Comment: ok, first off I changed your paths to relative paths, not absolute (c:\). Second, I closed off your div (</div>). I replaced the paths to the javascript with versions hosted on a CDN. You could use your local ones if you wanted, with relative paths.  Also, your ( type="text/javascript ) was missing a closing ". Glad you have it working!

Comment: Ooh! I will look back to this post as a reminder if I mess something like this up again. I really need to work on my ability to find small holes in my code.

Comment: Don't beat yourself up over it. Everyone makes these small mistakes that often take an outside look to see.